# 'Paramter value' is missing in props validation react/prop-types error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, components, eslint

I have two components in my react app say `alpha` & `bravo` and all I'm doing is passing a parameter from `alpha` to `bravo` and using the results back in `alpha` after some manipulation in `bravo`. Here's the sample code:

```
var alpha = React.createClass({
  state = {
    value : 'someValue'
  }
  render(){
    return(){
      <bravo value={this.state.value}/>
    }
  }
});
```

And

```
var bravo = React.createClass({
   state = {
     value : this.props.value
   }
   render(){
     return(){
        <h1>{this.state.value}</h2>
     }
   }
});
```

It's running perfectly fine and I'm getting the required results but at the same time I'm getting the following error:

```
 error  'value' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
```

I tried exploring the rest of questions here but none worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggle of almost an hour, I finally figured out the [solution](https://schibsted-engineers.gitbooks.io/frontend-pre-commit-rules/content/04-JSX%20Linting%20Rules/react_proptypes.html). In this case, adding following lines after `bravo` class worked:

```
bravo.propTypes = {
   value: React.PropTypes.string
};
```

So after adding these lines, the component code is as below:

```
var bravo = React.createClass({
  state = {
    value : this.props.value
  }
  render(){
    return(){
       <h1>{this.state.value}</h2>
    }
  }
});
bravo.propTypes = {
   value: React.PropTypes.string
};
export default bravo;
```

Comment: FYI, since the error is a linting error, if you don't want to add `propTypes`, you can also always disable the rule.

Comment: Thanks @loganfsmyth. Will definitely try it out

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html):

> With React.createClass(), you need to define propTypes as a property
>   on the passed object, and getDefaultProps() as a function on it

Define the [proptypes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.proptypes) for `bravo` and you should be good to go.

Another note- `createClass` accepts an Object so `render`, `state` and other key-value pairs must be keys with values using colons instead of equal signs. `state` and `render` should be `key: {key: value}` where each are separated by commas. Like:

```
var bravo = React.createClass({

   state: {
     value : this.props.value
   },

   render: function(){
     return <h1>{this.state.value}</h2>
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try something like

```
var Alpha = React.createClass({
  state = { value: 'someValue' }
  valueChanger: function() {
    var newVal;
    // change this.state.value and set it to newVal.
    this.setState( {value: newVal} );
  }
  render: function() {
    <Bravo value={this.valueChanger} />
  }
});
```

This way you keep the state in the top level component. Then you do...

```
var Bravo = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    <h1>{this.props.value}</h1>
  }
});
```

Comment: already tried many things like that but none worked. I'd updated an answer here that just worked.